# Problemas al detectar que checkbox ,de entre varios de un html,se está marcando

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo un grupo de checkboxes creados con html con datos provinentes de un ajax,cuyo programatorio es el siguiente

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'get',
   url: '/ajax/proveedores/albaranespendientes',
   data: {"id": id_0},
   dataType: "json",
   success: function (albaranes) {
   var numero = parseInt(Object.keys(albaranes).length);
   var html='';                            
   if ( numero>0 ) {
     for ( var i=0 ; i<numero; i++) {
     id = albaranes[i].id;
     html += "<input type='checkbox'  data-id="+albaranes[i].id+" data-importe="+albaranes[i].total+" class='facturar' value='"+id+"' name='albaranes[]'>   Albarán número "+albaranes[i].albaran+", con fecha "+albaranes[i].fecha.dateenglishtospanish()+" con un importe de "+toFormat(albaranes[i].total,2)+"€ <br>";
                            }
     $("#albaranesfacturar").html(html);
     $("#albaranesfacturar").css("display", "block");
     $("#factura-totales").css("display","block");
     } else {
     html = "No hay albaranes pendientes de Facturar.";
     $("#albaranesfacturar").html(html);
     $("#albaranesfacturar").css("display", "block");
     $("#factura-totales")                                            
      }
     }
     })
```

El numero de líneas que contiene el resultado del ajax pueden ser varias, al marcar o desmarcar cualquiera de los checkboxes resultantes ,acumulo los importes de los albaranes con:

```
     $(".facturar").each(function(){
     if( $(this).prop("checked") ) {
            c++
      base = parseFloat(base) + parseFloat($(this).data("importe"));
     }
     });
```

Necesito saber que línea del html estoy marcando o desmarcando , puesto que cada acción conduce a un resultado diferente, lo he intentado con el siguiente programa

```
        $("#albaranesfacturar").on("click",".facturar",function (e) {
        var id=$(this).data("id");
        $("#id-checkbox").val(id);

        var c=0;
        var base = 0;
          if($("#checkbox").is(':checked')) {  
                alert("Está activado"   );  
          } else {  
        alert("No está activado");  
         }  
});
```

Pero el resultado no es el esperado
Gracias anticipadas

Comment: podrias ser un poco mas claro... que deseas hacer, un ejemplo con datos de entrada y el resultado esperado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes varios errores, el primero de ellos es que no estás encerrando entre comillas los atributos de *checkboxes*; luego, en cada iteración del ciclo asignas contenido HTML y atributos para mostrar elementos.

En cuanto a la forma de generar los *checkboxes*, te recomiendo usar [plantillas de texto](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/template_strings), encerrando la cadena entre acentos graves e incluyendo las variables de esta forma: `${nombre_de_variable_o_funcion}`

```
var html = '';
if(numero > 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < numero; i++) {
        id = albaranes[i].id;
        html += `<input type='checkbox' data-albaran="${albaranes[i].albaran}" data-importe="${albaranes[i].total}" class="facturar" value="${id}" name="albaranes[]"> Albarán número ${albaranes[i].albaran}, con fecha ${albaranes[i].fecha.dateenglishtospanish()} con un importe de ${toFormat(albaranes[i].total,2)}€ <br>`;
    }

} else {
    html = "No hay albaranes pendientes de Facturar.";
}
$("#albaranesfacturar").html(html);
$("#albaranesfacturar").css("display", "block");
$("#factura-totales").css("display","block");
```

Después, creas una función para obtener todos los elementos marcados, junto con sus datos:

- No es necesario *data-id*, porque lo estás incluyendo en *value*
- Agregas *data-albaran* y *data-importe* con los datos correspondientes
- Obtienes los elementos por clase `$('.facturar')` y asignas evento *onclick*
- En la función del evento recorres solo los marcados `$('.facturar:checked')`
- Obtienes datos: ID desde *value* y los otros dos con `.data('atributo')`
- Generas HTML de la lista y calculas total

```js
// Contenido html y total a facturar
let html, total;

// Asignas onclick a todos los checkboxes, llamando una función
$('.facturar').on('click', chkFactura);

// Creas la función para manejar todos los marcados
function chkFactura() {
    // Inicializas lista y total
    html = '';
    total = 0;
    // Recorres todos los marcados para agregarlos a la lista
    $('.facturar:checked').each((index, item) => chkList(item));
    // Asignas HTML a la lista y agregas total
    $('#seleccionados').html(html);
    $('#total').html(`Total a facturar: ${total}`);
}

function chkList(item) {
    let id = $(item).val();
    let albaran = $(item).data('albaran');
    let importe = parseFloat($(item).data('importe'));
    html += `<li>ID: ${id}, Albarán ${albaran}, Importe: ${importe}</li>`;
    total += importe;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='checkbox' data-albaran="1" data-importe="123" class="facturar" value="1" name="albaranes[]"> Albarán número 1, con fecha 04/08/2020 con un importe de 123€ <br>
<input type='checkbox' data-albaran="2" data-importe="456" class="facturar" value="2" name="albaranes[]"> Albarán número 2, con fecha 04/08/2020 con un importe de 123€ <br>
<input type='checkbox' data-albaran="3" data-importe="789" class="facturar" value="3" name="albaranes[]"> Albarán número 3, con fecha 04/08/2020 con un importe de 123€ <br>

<ul id="seleccionados"></ul>
<div id="total">Total a facturar: 0</div>
```